# How can I return Stream<UserEntity> from firebase?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I want to return user data from firebase as a stream as UserEntity
I have this but it doen't work. Can you help me?

```
  @override
  Stream<UserEntity> getSingleUser(String uid) {
   final user= firebaseFirestore.collection('users').where("uid", isEqualTo: uid);
    return user.snapshots().map((event) => event.docs.map((e) => UserModel.fromSnapshot(e));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `data()` on `docs` to get that data you want:

```
@override
  Stream<UserEntity> getSingleUser(String uid) {
   final user= firebaseFirestore.collection('users').where("uid", isEqualTo: uid);
    return user.snapshots().map((event) => event.docs.map((e) => UserModel.fromSnapshot(e.data()));//<--- change this
  }
```